# How to export Selenium Test Suite/Case as C#

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

In the older version of the Selenium IDE you used to be able to export a test case as different languages, however, I am not seeing that option on the newer IDE...

Is it possible to export the test suite/case as C# in the newer IDE?

Answer (score 1):

The closest I have found is the option to export to Java. https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/code-export/

The important bits require minimal changes to use in a C# project.

Answer (score -1):

```
npm i @seleniumhq/code-export-csharp-commons
```